Android Permissios
I'm wondering when permissions are needed from the user for apps targeting Android 10+ (SDK 29+)? The purpose is to save a PDF file to shared storage. I read from sources that permission is no longer required from the user to create files in external app-specific scoped storage and shared storage. I don't quite understand the whole picture properly and why permission doesn't need to be requested.
Sources:
"As of Android 10 (API 29), you no longer need storage permissions to add files to shared storage. This means that you can add images to the gallery, record videos and save them to shared storage, or download PDF invoices without having to request storage permissions. If your app only adds files to shared storage and does not query images or videos, you should stop requesting storage permissions and set a maxSdkVersion of API 28 in your AndroidManifest.xml" https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/08/choosing-right-storage-experience.html (In order to read files, permission is still required?)
"To give users more control over their files and to limit file clutter, apps that target Android 10 (API level 29) and higher are given scoped access into external storage, or scoped storage, by default. Such apps have access only to the app-specific directory on external storage, as well as specific types of media that the app has created." https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage
I understand the purpose is to improve privacy, but how? I would greatly appreciate clarification on the matter :)

"I understand the purpose is to improve privacy, but how?" -- they do not want arbitrary apps to be able to read all files on external storage, or to even know what all the files are.
